# After enabling some xposed modules, my LG G2 (AT&T) is stuck in a error loop

Tags: boot-loop

Whenever I boot it up it says "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped.". It does allow me to hit ok, however when I hit ok I have about 1 second before it pops up again. Due to the passcode lock on my phone I am unable to get past the lockscreen as it wipes the input box everytime the popup box pops up. Despite the System UI apparently failing everything does seem to be functional behind the pop up. In the 1 second periods between pop ups I am able to interact with it. The status bar and the buttons on the bottom are not visible, however the rest of the lockscreen (including widgets) is.

The phone is rooted, however I had not gotten around to installing a custom bootloader yet. Debugging is enabled, however the device is listed as "offline" according to "adb devices". Due to this I am unable to install TWRP so as to flash the zip to disable xposed.

All of the above is still true in safe mode, the exact same thing happens.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would prefer to keep the data on it, however if nothing else a factory reset would be fine.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what xposed modules you enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these two threads

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432476

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2475045

If u still have Problem post here Will Help u .....

**EDIT:**

1.Turn off the G2 by holding down the power button and keeping it held down until the screen goes black, then continue to hold it for a few seconds after it goes black to make sure it shut down.

2.Plug the G2 into the computer via the USB cable while holding Volume Up at the same time to put it into download mode.

Comment: I can't seem to get it into download mode. Is safemode the same thing?

Comment: See my Edit.If it is helpful Tick it ...

Comment: Answers that contain only links [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Instead of saying "Follow this thread", please summarize what the thread is saying. Your answer should be complete by itself (without links), but having links as support is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem: after a xposed module update I restarted and it got stuck in the Samsung logo (I'm using Samsung Galaxy Core ). I've been digging everywhere on net and digged in XDA too.

What solved my issue:

1. I got into [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode) (removed battery and put it back in then turned on the device and kept on pressing <kbd>volume down</kbd> button till it got into safe mode).
2. Went straight into *Settings->application manager->all* and uninstalled *Xposed installer,*
3. then did a restart.

BINGO that's it, Everything came to normal. Just had to uninstall xposed installer (Better than wiping cache and restoring factory settings).